# Alterar string usando parâmetro de função

Tags: c, string, funções, parâmetros

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void menu_principal(char* monstro1, char* monstro2){
    int escolha;
    char monstro[20];
    printf("King of Tokyo\n\n");
    printf("Jogador escolha um monstro:\n---------------------------\n");
    printf("1-Godzilla\n2-Feto Gigante Zumbi Nazista\n3-Pac-Man\n4-Blanca\n5-Penha\n6-Nemesis\n\n0-SAIR\n\n");
    do{
        scanf("%d", &escolha);
    }
    while(escolha<0 || escolha>6);
    if(escolha==0){
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("VOCE ESCOLHEU:");
    if(escolha==1){
        char monstro[30]="Godzilla";
        printf("%s\n\n",monstro);
    }
    else if(escolha==2){    
        char monstro[30]="Feto Gigante Zumbi Nazista";
        printf("%s\n\n",monstro);
    }
    else if(escolha==3){
        char monstro[30]="Pac-Man";
        printf("%s\n\n",monstro);
    }
    else if(escolha==4){
        char monstro[30]="Blanca";
        printf("%s\n\n",monstro);
    }
    else if(escolha==5){
        char monstro[30]="Penha";
        printf("%s\n\n",monstro);
    }
    else if(escolha==6){
        char monstro[30]="Nemesis";
        printf("%s\n\n",monstro);
    } 
    *monstro1=monstro; 
}

int main(){
    char monstromain1[30]=".";
    char monstromain2[30]="..";
    menu_principal(monstromain1,monstromain2);
    printf("%s",monstromain1);
    return 0;
}
```

Eu não estou conseguindo alterar o valor de `monstromain1` usando a função. Ao executar eu recebo o erro

> main.c:42:14: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
>        *monstro1=monstro;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O código está complicado demais e difícil de ler, isto acaba fazendo ficar difícil de achar o problema e ele é o fato de não estar copiando o texto para a variável que deseja, isto deve ocorrer com [`strcpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy). Este código não é exatamente seguro, mas para um exercício está bom:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void menu_principal(char *monstro1, char* monstro2){
    printf("King of Tokyo\n\n");
    printf("Jogador escolha um monstro:\n---------------------------\n");
    printf("1-Godzilla\n2-Feto Gigante Zumbi Nazista\n3-Pac-Man\n4-Blanca\n5-Penha\n6-Nemesis\n\n0-SAIR\n\n");
    int escolha;
    do { scanf("%d", &escolha); } while (escolha < 0 || escolha > 6);
    if (escolha == 0) exit(0);
    char *monstros[] = { "", "Godzilla", "Feto Gigante Zumbi Nazista", "Pac-Man", "Blanca", "Penha", "Nemesis" };
    strcpy(monstro1, monstros[escolha]);
    printf("VOCE ESCOLHEU: %s\n\n", monstro1);
}

int main(){
    char monstromain1[30]=".";
    char monstromain2[30]="..";
    menu_principal(monstromain1, monstromain2);
    printf("%s", monstromain1);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/qJ2Slz). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/onjsxtic-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/CopyString.c).